# Call a method every x minutes

Tags: java, android, methods, automation, call

currently I have a application which can send notifications, I would like this application to be able to send these notifications automatically every x minutes (for example, 15 minutes is the default). The app may or may not be currently running when this notification should be sent.

After some reading, I've determined that an AlarmManager would be used here, but I cannot figure out how to call a method from it. I already have the notification code, I just need a way to call it every x minutes.

I'm very new to this, this is my first practice app (having experience in C#, but little in Java).

Thanks, David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

If you are unclear, go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#service_start)  tutorial

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like it should work, though, if I have my method in my MainActivity.class then how should I call that from the service, or should I refactor it to it's own class and create a instance of that?

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial I have linked above? There are a couple of things you have to do: register the service in your AndroidManifest.xml.  The implementing class (MyService in the example above) must extend the Service class or one of its subclasses. Please go through the tutorial first, it does include some of the sample code.

Comment: I have read the example, but I still do not fully understand how to then call my notification method from the service?

Comment: Notification code goes inside the MyService class onCreate and/or onStartCommand methods.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `IntentService`. Inside it, just start a new `Thread`. In the `Thread.run()`, put an infinite while loop to call your notification code and `Thread.sleep(15 * 60 * 1000)`....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule your tasks with the specified interval don't use flags `AlarmManager.RTC` and `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` with method `alarm.setRepeating(...)`. Because in this case alarm will be bounded to the device's real time clock. So changing the system time may cause alarm to misbehave. You must use flags `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. In this case `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` will serve as a basis for scheduling an alarm.

The code will look like:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + checkIntervalMillis, checkIntervalMillis, pendingIntent);
```

If you want your long running task to be executed when device in the sleep mode I recommend to use WakefulIntentService library by CommonsWare: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful